# How do you smoothly move a graphics object 360 degrees in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I'm trying to make a Geometry Wars style game and I am at a roadblock. I have been trying to figure out a way to move my graphics object around smoothly. But it only moves in one direction. For example, if I press the up button then it goes up and then when I press the right button on top of that then I move diagonally towards the top-right. But I want my object to smoothly turn from going straight up to going towards the top-right. This is my code so far:

```
public class MoveTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0;
 private Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<Integer>();
private static int WIDTH = 800;
private static int HEIGHT = 600;
private double d = 0;
private double topSpeed = 0;
private boolean stop = false;
private double a = 0;

PVector location;
PVector velocity;
PVector acceleration;

public MoveTest() {
  location = new PVector(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2);
  velocity = new PVector(0,0);
  acceleration = new PVector(0,0);
  topSpeed = 5.0;
  t.start();
  addKeyListener(this);
  setFocusable(true);
  setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g2.drawOval((int)location.x, (int)location.y, 40, 40);
}

void update() {
  velocity.add(acceleration);
  if(stop == false) {
    velocity.limit(topSpeed);
  }
  else {
    velocity.decellerate(0);
  }
  location.add(velocity);    
}

public void north() {
  acceleration = new PVector(0,-5);
}

public void south() {
  acceleration = new PVector(0,5);
}

public void west() {
  acceleration = new PVector(-5,0);
}

public void east() {
  acceleration = new PVector(5,0);
}

public void northEast() {
  acceleration = new PVector(5,-5);
}

public void northWest() {
  acceleration = new PVector(-5,-5);
}

public void southEast() {
  acceleration= new PVector(5,5);
}

public void southWest() {
  acceleration = new PVector(-5,5);
}

public void stop(){
  stop = true;
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  //System.out.println("" + velocity.x + " " + velocity.y);
  repaint();
  update();
  checkEdges();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

int code = e.getKeyCode();

stop = false;

pressed.add(code);

if(pressed.size() > 1) {
  if(pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W) && pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
    northEast();
  }
  if(pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W) && pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
    northWest();
  }
  if(pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S) && pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
    southEast();
   }
  if(pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S) && pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
    southWest();
  } 
}

else if(pressed.size() == 1){
  if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
    north();
  }
  if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
    south();
  }
  if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
    east();
  }
  if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
    west();
  }
}
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
  if(pressed.size() == 0) {
    stop();
  }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

void checkEdges() {
  if(location.x > WIDTH) {
    location.x = 0;
  }
  else if(location.x < 0) {
    location.x  = WIDTH;
  }
  if(location.y > HEIGHT) {
    location.y = 0;
  }
  else if(location.y < 0) {
    location.y = HEIGHT;
  }
}

}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
//MoveTest
topSpeed = 5.0;

//update
velocity.add(acceleration);
if(stop == false) {
  velocity.limit(topSpeed);

//south
acceleration = new PVector(0,5);
```

So your acceleration is always 5 or 7 (which probably is an error) units if you press your key. Then you add this to your velocity which is then limited to 5. Your acceleration is so strong you almost have no inertia. Try smaller accelerations or a larger topSpeed and it should become smoother.

Aside: are you compensating for frame rate? I don't see it in your code but I don't know the `PVector` implementation.

Comment: I see your point. So should I be adding the acceleration vector or subtracting to make it move faster or slower instead and then set the limit to a specific topSpeed so it doesn't just keep accelerating? Also I got the idea for the PVector class from http://processing.org/learning/pvector/

Comment: I'm having trouble making a cap on the acceleration. For example my object will not move in diagonals. If I press the right key then it goes right, but when i press the up key with it, then it goes straight up.Do you have any advice or any good sites for information about what i am trying to do? I've been having trouble finding good information about this.

Comment: @Heisenburg I think it would be important for you to first decide on a motion model. One such model would be a car that has a heading and a speed which can be steered independently and movement is always in the direction of the heading. Another would be a "space ship" where you have a 2D/3D velocity and can change it by applying accelerations in any direction. It might be best to think about this and ask again [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).